# how to start video track which is opened using getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I am trying to create a toggle button on video track of getUserMedia

```
toggleVideo = () => {
  let { video } = this.state;
  video = !video
  let camera = document.getElementById("camera");
  this.videoStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
    console.log('999 :: track value', track)
    track.readyState == 'live' && track.kind === 'video' &&
      track.stop()
  })
  video === false && camera.src = "";
};
<video id="camera"></video>
```

using this way i am able to stop the video track but how can i restart the video track.

Comment: you'd want `track.play()`

Comment: @JaromandaX Uncaught TypeError: track.play is not a function